# .isspace() on a dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to replace values containing only spaces in a dataframe.
I tried to use the following code but it replaces all the values from the column:

```
books['original_title'] = books.apply(lambda row: row['title']
                                    if (str(row['original_title']).isspace() == True)
                                    else row['title'],
                                    axis=1)
```

For example, for this df:

```
books = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['If You Take a Mouse to School', 'Sea of Swords', 'SHOULD NOT CHANGE'], 
              'original_title': ['   ', ' ', 'NOT CHANGING']})
```

The expected answer corresponds to the following dataframe:

```
expected_answer = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['If You Take a Mouse to School', 'Sea of Swords', 'SHOULD NOT CHANGE'], 
              'original_title': ['If You Take a Mouse to School', 'Sea of Swords', 'NOT CHANGING']})
```

But I'm only getting this:

```
answer = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['If You Take a Mouse to School', 'Sea of Swords', 'SHOULD NOT CHANGE'], 
              'original_title': ['If You Take a Mouse to School', 'Sea of Swords', 'SHOULD NOT CHANGE']})
```

I'd be grateful if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

First use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) to replace the `empty spaces` with `NaN` values, then use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill the missing values in `original_title` column from the values from `title` column:

```
books['original_title'] = (
    books['original_title'].replace(
        r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).fillna(books['title'])
)
```

Result:

```
print(books)
                           title                 original_title
0  If You Take a Mouse to School  If You Take a Mouse to School
1                  Sea of Swords                  Sea of Swords
2              SHOULD NOT CHANGE                   NOT CHANGING
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for replace by mask - remove multiple spaces by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and then converting to bool for convert these values to `False`s:

```
mask = books['original_title'].str.strip().astype(bool)
books['original_title'] = books['original_title'].where(mask, books['title'])

print (books)
                           title                 original_title
0  If You Take a Mouse to School  If You Take a Mouse to School
1                  Sea of Swords                  Sea of Swords
2              SHOULD NOT CHANGE                   NOT CHANGING
```

**Detail**:

```
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: original_title, dtype: bool
```

Similar idea is test by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for test zero or multiples spaces by regex and set values by `True`s by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
mask1 = books['original_title'].str.contains('^\s*$')
books['original_title'] = books['original_title'].mask(mask1, books['title'])
```

**Detail**:

```
print (mask1)
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: original_title, dtype: bool
```

[`Series.str.isspace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isspace.html) is possible use, but not working if empty space (data was changed):

```
books = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['If You Take a Mouse to School', 'Sea of Swords', 'SHOULD NOT CHANGE'], 
              'original_title': ['   ', '', 'NOT CHANGING']})

mask = books['original_title'].str.isspace()
books['original_title'] = books['original_title'].mask(mask, books['title'])

print (books)
                           title                 original_title
0  If You Take a Mouse to School  If You Take a Mouse to School
1                  Sea of Swords                               
2              SHOULD NOT CHANGE                   NOT CHANGING
```